# How to use jquery to get style attribute of an element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a div which contains a h2 tag and a p tag.

i wan a case where if the div is hovered (moverenter), the background colors of the h2 tag and the p tag get exchanged and when move leave it resets.

I am looking at this solution because i have many of the panels with different h2 tag and p tags. my approve so far:

```
<div class="panel">
  <h2 class="title">This is the title</h2>
  <p class="desc">This is a decription</p>
</div>
```

on the jQuery i tried

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $(".panel").mouseenter(function(){

    exchange($(this));
}).mouseleave(function(){

    exchange($(this));
});

function exchange(e){
 var x = e.children(".title"),
     y = e.children(".desc");

 x.css("background", "y.css('background')");
}

});
```

I am sorry, just learning JS

NB: since i have not gotten it working, i was also looking for a smooth transition effect on the exchange

Comment: `x.css("background", y.css('background'));` - `y.css('background')` is not a string literal, it is a statement whose value has to be passed to another function

Comment: Create classes instead of style css.

Comment: why don't you just use css `:hover`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean something like

```js
$(".panel").mouseenter(function () {
    var $this = $(this),
        $h2 = $this.children('h2'),
        $p = $this.children('p'),
        h2c = $h2.css('background-color'),
        pc = $p.css('background-color');

    $h2.css('background-color', pc);
    $p.css('background-color', h2c);
}).mouseleave(function () {
    $(this).children('h2, p').css('background-color', '');
})
```

```css
.panel h2 {
    background-color: lightgrey;
}
.panel p {
    background-color: lightblue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="panel">
    <h2 class="title">This is the title</h2>
    <p class="desc">This is a decription</p>
</div>
<div class="panel">
    <h2 class="title">This is the title</h2>
    <p class="desc">This is a decription</p>
</div>
<div class="panel">
    <h2 class="title">This is the title</h2>
    <p class="desc">This is a decription</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I didn't check everything but that won't work :

```
x.css("background", "y.css('background')");
```

Try something like :

```
var bgY = y.css('background');
x.css("background", bgY);
```

Comment: y.css('background') is not getting the background color

Answer (score 0):

I  made minor changes to your code

Hope it solves your problem.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>      
    <script src="Scripts/jquery-ui-1.10.4.js"></script>
    <link href="Content/jquery-ui-1.10.4.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $(".panel").mouseenter(function () {
                $(".panel").toggle();
            }).mouseleave(function () {
                $(".panel").toggle();
            });
        })
    </script>

</head>
<body>
 <div class="panel" style="display:none" >
  <h2 class="title" style="background-color:gray">This is the title</h2>
  <p class="desc"  style="background-color:lightgray">This is a decription</p>
 </div>
 <div class="panel" style="display:block" >
  <h2 class="title" style="background-color:lightgray">This is the title</h2>
  <p class="desc"  style="background-color:gray">This is a decription</p>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

For only exchanging `CSS` of `p` and `h2` elements :-

```
  $('div.panel').on('hover',function(){
      $(this).find('.title').css('background-color','blue');
      $(this).find('.desc').css('background-color','green');
   },function(){
       $(this).find('.title').css('background-color','green');
       $(this).find('.desc').css('background-color','blue');
   });
```

Now suppose , Lets say you set some `background-color` to your `p` and `h2` elements .

**CSS**

```
   .title{
        background-color: green;
     }
    .desc{
        background-color: blue;
     }
```

**SCRIPT**

```
     $('div.panel').on('hover',function(){
      $(this).find('.title').css('background-color','blue');
       $(this).find('.desc').css('background-color','green');
   },function(){
       $(this).find('.title').removeAttr('style');
        $(this).find('.desc').removeAttr('style');
   });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can find all the children of the panel and change their backgroundcolor.

You can do this on mouseEnter:

```
$(".panel").children().css("background-color","red");
```

And on mouseLeave take another backgroundcolor.

Answer (score 0):

And for the animation part, if you're working with simple background colors you could use animate().

```
...
function exchange(e)
{
  var x = e.children(".title"),
      y = e.children(".desc");
      bg1 = x.css('background-color'),
      bg2 = y.css('background-color');

  x.animate({ "background-color": bg2 }, 1500);
  y.animate({ "background-color": bg1 }, 1500);
}
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you are a working example http://jsfiddle.net/9a1qe9q9/2/

jQuery

```
$(".panel").mouseenter(function () {

    exchange($(this));

}).mouseleave(function () {

    exchange($(this));
});

function exchange(e) {
    var x = e.children(".title"),
        y = e.children(".desc"),
        xColor = x.css('background'),
        yColor = y.css('background');

    x.css("background", yColor);
    y.css("background", xColor);
}
```